# Why is R not returning a warning for unused argument in anova()? Must use "type =" in anova(lme, type = 'marginal')

Tags: r

My lme object is

`lmeObject <- lmer(FvD ~ Group:run + Group+run+ (1 | record_id) , data=FvD, na.action = na.omit)`

I just realized that

```
anova(lmeObject, 'marginal')
```

is not doing anything different than

```
anova(lme)
```

To specify marginal must add "type = "

```
anova(lmeObject, type = 'marginal')
```

The problem is I am not getting a warning for unused argument 'marginal'. Why is R not warning in this case? What other cases that R won't give a warning/to watch for?

Comment: Can you supply a more complete code example? It's not clear what `lme` or `lme_FvD` refer to, nor that you are (presumably) using `nlme::anova.lme`, as opposed to base `anova`.

Comment: I updated it to lmeobject. Hope this will make more sense!